# Require spline to be convex

Tags: r, spline

I need to fit a spline to a set of data and the resulting function is required to be monotonically decreasing and convex.  The data I am passing to splinefun are guaranteed to have these properties, but this does not guarantee that the resulting function is convex.  Is there any way to fit a spline to a set of data and require that the resulting function is convex?

Comment: Hi, I would ask this in one of SO's subsites such as Gamedev, MathOverflow or Cross Validated. Sorry I'm a Matlab guy, and it's bedtime. Just a tip.

Comment: Can you share any example code, data or expected outcome to simplify answering this query?

Comment: Have you seen this by the way: http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~meyer/penspl.htm ?

Comment: Have you try using splinefun() with method="monoH.FC"?

Answer (score 8):

First providing some example data:

```
x = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
y = c(2,1, 0.59, 0.27, 0.25, -0.23, -0.45)
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
```

### Monotonic Spline

We can do a monotonic spline with `splinefun(x,y,"monoH.FC")` as @fang suggests.

```
# Setting up Monotonic Spline
MonoSpline = splinefun(x,y,"monoH.FC")
#Getting Ready for plotting Monotonic Spline
xArray = seq(0,6,0.01)
MonoResult = MonoSpline(xArray)
```

### Monotonic Convex Spline (With scam package)

For a monotonic convex spline you need to use the `scam` package. We can then:

```
# Setting up Monotonic Convex Spline
# install.packages("scam")
require(scam)
MonoConvexSpline <- scam(y~s(x,k=4,bs="mdcx",m=1),data=dat)
MonoConvexSplinePredict =function(Test){
  predict.scam(MonoConvexSpline,data.frame(x = Test))
} 
#Getting Ready for plotting Monotonic Convex Spline
MonoConvexSplineResult = MonoConvexSplinePredict(xArray)
```

Note the following:

1. The option `bs="mdcx"` means we want an decreasing convex spline. If you want increasing convex, decreasing concave etc then look up the appropriate `bs` value [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/scam/docs/shape.constrained.smooth.terms).
2. If you put non-montonic data into the `splinefun(x,y,"monoH.FC")` function we get an error.
3. If you put non-convex data into the `scam` function then you will still get a spline. The data is changed so that small convexities are changed to being convex. There is no warning of this so be careful however because your data might look completely different. As an example, the below plot was made using the same code as above except we had `bs="mdcv"` for a decreasing concave function:

### Monotonic Convex Spline (With cobs package)

```
# Convex Cobs Spline
library(cobs)
spCobs = cobs(x , y, constraint = c("decrease", "convex"), nknots = 8)
spCobsResults = predict(spCobs, xArray)[,2]
```

### Plotting Everything

Then plotting them with

```
Plot = qplot(xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
Plot = Plot + geom_line(aes(xArray,MonoResult            , colour = "Monotonic Spline"            ))
Plot = Plot + geom_line(aes(xArray,MonoConvexSplineResult, colour = "Monotonic Convex scam Spline"))
Plot = Plot + geom_line(aes(xArray,spCobsResults         , colour = "Monotonic Convex cobs Spline"))
Plot
```

[image: Monotonic and Convex Splines]

### Speed

- It takes much longer to predict points using the `scam` function than
  using the monotonic spline or cobs spline. You can see this from the below microbenchmark
- The cobs spline and scam splines take much longer to initially calculate than the general monotonic spline however.

.

```
# Prediction
library(microbenchmark)
    microbenchmark(
      MonoSpline(xArray),
      predict.scam(MonoConvexSpline,data.frame(x = xArray)),
      predict(spCobs, xArray)[,2] 
    )

Unit: microseconds
                                                   expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
                                     MonoSpline(xArray)  141.540  147.8175  223.3695  156.9490  167.9830 1593.456   100
 predict.scam(MonoConvexSpline, data.frame(x = xArray)) 2778.655 2838.0095 3161.2282 2914.8665 3153.4285 6168.741   100
                           predict(spCobs, xArray)[, 2]  125.179  133.1690  155.1226  145.1535  162.2755  366.784   100

# Calculating Spline
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  splinefun(x,y,"monoH.FC"),
  scam(y~s(x,k=4,bs="mdcx",m=1),data=dat),
  cobs(x , y, constraint = c("decrease", "convex"), nknots = 8) 
)

Unit: microseconds
                                                         expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq       max neval
                                  splinefun(x, y, "monoH.FC")     90.175    127.462    411.6407    153.7155    198.993  24877.47   100
        scam(y ~ s(x, k = 4, bs = "mdcx", m = 1), data = dat) 166769.270 196719.139 231631.5321 224372.7940 265074.525 355734.37   100
 cobs(x, y, constraint = c("decrease", "convex"), nknots = 8) 145511.335 172887.618 203786.0940 202997.4795 228688.607 347661.29   100
```

Comment: Note there's also the conSpline package that can fit concave or convex splines, and that this is faster than the options above (the optimisation is done in Rcpp). And there's the cgam package, though that's also quite slow...

Comment: Also note that cobs is ca. 10 times faster if you do spCobs <- cobs(x , y, constraint = c("decrease", "convex"), knots=seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=6), nknots = 6), i.e. if you also specify the desired knots with the knots argument, as that disables the time consuming adaptive knot selection....

Answer (score 1):

My other answer on this question showed the monotonic spline and the cobs and scam shape constrained splines. The problem with these shape constrained splines are that they are fairly slow and do not necessarily interpolate all of the datapoints.

### Schumaker Spline

I have released a package that implements the Schumaker spline which is monotonic and convex/concave if the data is monotonic and convex/concave. It is fast and interpolates all data points.

For an example:

```
#install.packages("schumaker")
library(schumaker)

x = seq(1,10)
y = -log(x)
xarray = seq(1,10,0.01)

SchumSpline = schumaker::Schumaker(x,y)
Schum0 = SchumSpline$Spline(xarray)
Schum1 = SchumSpline$DerivativeSpline(xarray)
Schum2 = SchumSpline$SecondDerivativeSpline(xarray)

plot(xarray, Schum0, type = "l", col = 4, ylim = c(-3,1), main = "Schumaker Spline and first two derivatives",
     ylab = "Spline and derivatives", xlab = "x")
points(x,y)
lines(xarray, Schum1, col = 2)
lines(xarray, Schum2, col = 3)
abline(h = 0, col = 1)
text(x=rep(8,8,8), y=c(-2, -0.5,+0.2), pos=4, labels=c('Spline', 'First Derivative', 'Second Derivative'))
```

[image: Schumaker Spline and Derivatives]

You can see the second derivative is always positive (This is not true for the normal monotonic spline. See the package's vignette).

Note that the spline will only be globally convex/concave if the data is globally convex/concave. This is unavoidable as this is an interpolating spline.

This spline is faster than the cobs and scam splines. It is slower to create than the monotonic spline but faster to evaluate. Full speed tests can be found in the vignette.